# How to pivot_longer on multiple columns with unequal numbers of comma-separated values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have messy-looking data where multiple columns have multiple comma-separated values:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Line = 1:2,
  Utterance = c("hi there", "how're ya"),
  A_aoi = c("C*B*C", "*"),
  A_aoi_dur = c("100,25,30,50,144", "200"),
  B_aoi = c("*A", "*A*A*C"),
  B_aoi_dur = c("777,876", "50,22,33,100,150,999")
)
```

What I'd like to do is `pivot_longer` so that each of the comma-separated values has their own row. I *can* accomplish this but it seems the way I'm accomplishing is anything but accomplished as it involves multiple intermediary steps and temporary `df`s making the code long-winded and heavy:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# first temporary `df`:
df1 <- df %>%
  select(-ends_with("dur")) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = ends_with("aoi"),
               names_to = "Speaker") %>%
  separate_rows(value, sep = "(?!^|$)") %>%
  mutate(Speaker = sub("^(.).*", "\\1", Speaker)) %>%
  rename(AOI = value)

# second temporary `df`:
df2 <- df %>%
  select(-ends_with("aoi")) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = ends_with("dur")) %>%
  separate_rows(value, sep = ",") %>%
  rename(Dur = value)

# final `df` (aka, the **expected outcome**):
df3 <- cbind(df1, df2[,4])

df3
   Line Utterance Speaker AOI Dur
1     1  hi there       A   C 100
2     1  hi there       A   *  25
3     1  hi there       A   B  30
4     1  hi there       A   *  50
5     1  hi there       A   C 144
6     1  hi there       B   * 777
7     1  hi there       B   A 876
8     2 how're ya       A   * 200
9     2 how're ya       B   *  50
10    2 how're ya       B   A  22
11    2 how're ya       B   *  33
12    2 how're ya       B   A 100
13    2 how're ya       B   * 150
14    2 how're ya       B   C 999
```

How can this transfomation be achieved more succintly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, is an option in [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/)

1. We rename the columns (`rename_with`) that `ends_with` '_aoi' by `paste`ing the '_AOI'
2. Reshape from 'wide' to 'long' - [`pivot_longer`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html)
3. Insert delimiter `,` in 'AOI' between each character to make common delimiter - `str_replace_all`
4. Finally, use [`separate_rows`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/1.1.3/topics/separate_rows) on the `,` delimiter

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    rename_with(~ str_c(., "_AOI"), ends_with("_aoi")) %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = contains("_"), 
      names_to = c("Speaker", ".value"), names_pattern = "^(.*)_([^_]+$)") %>% 
    mutate(AOI = str_replace_all(AOI, "(?<=.)(?=.)", ",")) %>% 
    separate_rows(c(AOI, dur), sep = ",", convert = TRUE)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 14 x 5
    Line Utterance Speaker AOI     dur
   <int> <chr>     <chr>   <chr> <int>
 1     1 hi there  A_aoi   C       100
 2     1 hi there  A_aoi   *        25
 3     1 hi there  A_aoi   B        30
 4     1 hi there  A_aoi   *        50
 5     1 hi there  A_aoi   C       144
 6     1 hi there  B_aoi   *       777
 7     1 hi there  B_aoi   A       876
 8     2 how're ya A_aoi   *       200
 9     2 how're ya B_aoi   *        50
10     2 how're ya B_aoi   A        22
11     2 how're ya B_aoi   *        33
12     2 how're ya B_aoi   A       100
13     2 how're ya B_aoi   *       150
14     2 how're ya B_aoi   C       999
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether this is really "more succinct", but here's an approach that does everything in a single pipe chain.

1. All the values in columns other than `Line` and `Utterance` are going to end up in value columns, so pivot them all longer
2. Separate out the `Speaker` from the column name
3. Pivot the value columns wider into the final shape (one column for `AOI`, one for `Dur`). This pattern of longer then wider with different keys is pretty common
4. Lastly, split up the values so that we can put them on their own rows. I don't think `separate_rows` handles different separators for columns well, especially where we need to split each character, so we can do it manually and `unnest` to get the desired output. Note that this depends on the `AOI` and the `Dur` having the same number of elements, which I'm assuming is true given the input.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(
  Line = 1:2,
  Utterance = c("hi there", "how're ya"),
  A_aoi = c("C*B*C", "*"),
  A_aoi_dur = c("100,25,30,50,144", "200"),
  B_aoi = c("*A", "*A*A*C"),
  B_aoi_dur = c("777,876", "50,22,33,100,150,999")
)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = matches("(aoi|dur)$"),
    names_to = "name",
    values_to = "value"
  ) %>%
  separate(name, into = c("Speaker", "aoi_dur"), sep = "_", extra = "merge") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = aoi_dur, values_from = value) %>%
  rename(AOI = aoi, Dur = aoi_dur) %>%
  mutate(
    AOI = str_split(AOI, pattern = ""),
    Dur = str_split(Dur, pattern = ",")
  ) %>%
  unnest(c(AOI, Dur))
#> # A tibble: 14 x 5
#>     Line Utterance Speaker AOI   Dur  
#>    <int> <chr>     <chr>   <chr> <chr>
#>  1     1 hi there  A       C     100  
#>  2     1 hi there  A       *     25   
#>  3     1 hi there  A       B     30   
#>  4     1 hi there  A       *     50   
#>  5     1 hi there  A       C     144  
#>  6     1 hi there  B       *     777  
#>  7     1 hi there  B       A     876  
#>  8     2 how're ya A       *     200  
#>  9     2 how're ya B       *     50   
#> 10     2 how're ya B       A     22   
#> 11     2 how're ya B       *     33   
#> 12     2 how're ya B       A     100  
#> 13     2 how're ya B       *     150  
#> 14     2 how're ya B       C     999
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>